# Jupyter Notebook kernel dies when trying to run matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm very new to Python and programming in general. I am trying to plot a simple graph using matplotlib in Jupyter notebooks and an error message keeps popping up saying that the kernel has died. I've tried reinstalling Anaconda and Jupyter. I've also tried "conda install nomkl" and the problem persists. Here are some screen shots
[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1hEK.png)
[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQPX.png)

Here is a copy of my terminal window:

```
[I 15:01:58.001 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from 
/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 15:01:58.002 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is 
/Applications/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 15:01:58.012 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/ScottJohnson
[I 15:01:58.013 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:01:58.013 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/? 
token=68e1eadc99bad8ce436618fa11bf3b585bd49aaeab6a6e99
[I 15:01:58.013 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/? 
token=68e1eadc99bad8ce436618fa11bf3b585bd49aaeab6a6e99
[I 15:01:58.014 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels 
(twice to skip confirmation).
[C 15:01:58.032 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/ScottJohnson/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3489-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=68e1eadc99bad8ce436618fa11bf3b585bd49aaeab6a6e99
    or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=68e1eadc99bad8ce436618fa11bf3b585bd49aaeab6a6e99
[W 15:02:22.969 NotebookApp] Notebook Desktop/Python Class/CourseMaterial/06 - 
Functions/0615 - Birth statistics graphic.ipynb is not trusted
[I 15:02:23.728 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0d91235f-3ea8-46a2-ade3-ca33b2bd1049
[I 15:02:47.683 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 0d91235f-3ea8-46a2-ade3-ca33b2bd1049 restarted
[I 15:02:59.703 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 0d91235f-3ea8-46a2-ade3-ca33b2bd1049 restarted
[I 15:04:33.401 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/Python Class/CourseMaterial/06 - 
Functions/0615 - Birth statistics graphic.ipynb
[I 15:06:23.399 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/Python Class/CourseMaterial/06 - 
Functions/0615 - Birth statistics graphic.ipynb
[I 15:08:24.103 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/Python Class/CourseMaterial/06 - 
Functions/0615 - Birth statistics graphic.ipynb
[I 15:09:08.714 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 0d91235f-3ea8-46a2-ade3-ca33b2bd1049 restarted
[I 15:10:23.359 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/Python Class/CourseMaterial/06 - 
Functions/0615 - Birth statistics graphic.ipynb
```

Comment: Try executing the matplotlib import first of all.

Comment: In general, when you get an error like that, execute your code line by line, to see which line causes the error. From your screenshot we could not tell whether the problem is caused by the import or the plotting, because both are in the same notebook cell.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `plt.show()` in the notebook.

Comment: I tried running only the import and the kernel died

Comment: Maybe a hardware problem? Can you try running that matplotlib import line from a shell, without using the notebook?